# Error CS0234: The type or namespace error in build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, devops, pipeline

while building the pipeline in Azure DevOps with .NET Framework Code, I am getting in VS Build task

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XXXX' does not exist in the namespace 'XXXX' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

[image]

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't build - and show it as *text* rather than as a screenshot. (In particular, it looks like the problem is in AmazonCloudDownloader.cs line 177 - what does that code look like? What do you expect `file` to refer to there?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.